# UK: Is it safe to bypass a light switch?

Tags: wiring, lighting, uk

Is it safe to join the live & switched-live wires behind a switch so the light is permanently on?  And if so, what would be the best method (connector block, crimp, etc)?

Comment: Couldn't you just leave the switch on?

Comment: I don't know if they have something similar in the UK, but I installed a few of [these](http://www.amazon.com/Westek-SG1-Value-Switch-Guard/dp/B000NCV1SK) on switches that I didn't want anyone to touch.  They screw in right on top of the normal switch cover for and easy and decent looking solution.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's safe (or legal) to leave a non-functioning switch in place? That's a different question. It's safe to nut the two wires together otherwise, which is no different than having a junction, outlet, or whatever on the same circuit as always-on lighting.

Comment: @Tester101 Yes, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks, but I'm not considering alternatives. I just wish to know if what I'm planning is safe, and the best method to connect the wires.

Comment: @isherwood No, I'm just asking about the safety of connecting the wires together.

Comment: A minor, tiny point on safety: Are you going to turn off the breaker every time the bulb burns out?  I personally like to turn off the switch to swap a bulb although I know most people just change it regardless of if it's off or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can* safely bypass a switch.  It's no different than having a solid length of wire, or a closed switch (electrically speaking).

In the US, a twist-on wire connector (wire nut) would be the preferred connector. Though I believe the UK prefers other types of connectors, likely some type of screw terminal connector.  Take a trip to the local hardware store, to see what's available.

Once you make the connection, you can cover the box with a blank cover plate.

Answer (score 3):

You can

- Replace the switch with a key-operated switch. The type that have a slot for a "fish key" are probably the cheapest.
- Replace the switch with a 1-gang coverplate and connect the wires using a suitably rated (e.g. 5A) screw-terminal block. I don't know if this is legal. To replace the lightbulb you'd then have to go to the consumer unit (main panel) and turn off the MCB for lighting to that whole floor.

[image]
[image]  OR

[image]
[image]

switch and key are each about £1.20. That is cheaper and better than the alternative.

Comment: Thanks, but I just wish to know whether connecting the wires together with a suitable connector is safe to do, rather than having them go through a switch.